Adding regularizers to a layer create errors at training time with variable defined while building the graph of layer
I made a small model. It has a small layer that uses a variable "num_features" to be added to the graph. It works. If I add a regulariser (its not useful here, but was useful on the bigger model I was trying to implement) I get an error, but the error is telling me that it lost the "num_features" variable.
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
!pip install --upgrade keras

import os
import glob
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import data as tf_data

import keras
from keras import ops
from keras import layers

def subnet(inputs, num_features):

    bias = keras.initializers.Constant(np.eye(num_features).flatten())
    reg = keras.regularizers.OrthogonalRegularizer(factor=0.001, mode='rows')
    x = layers.Dense(
        num_features * num_features,
        kernel_initializer="zeros",
        bias_initializer=bias,
        activity_regularizer=reg,
    )(inputs)

    return x

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,))
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
x = subnet(x,8)

outputs = layers.Dense(10)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="example_model")
model.summary()

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype("float32") / 255

model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=2, validation_split=0.2)

The error I get is this:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-18-ffd0cf24302e> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 )
     11 
---> 12 history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=2, validation_split=0.2)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/numpy.py in eye(N, M, k, dtype)
   2363         M = N
   2364     # Making sure N, M and k are `int`
-> 2365     N, M, k = int(N), int(M), int(k)
   2366     if k >= M or -k >= N:
   2367         # tf.linalg.diag will raise an error in this case

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling Functional.call().

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

Arguments received by Functional.call():
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 784), dtype=float32)
  • training=False
  • mask=None

The argument of eye is the num_features I explicitly defined when making the graph of layer. If I remove the activity_regulariser I get no error at all. Why is the content of num_features modified during training?
